# Using Values of IGrouping

Tags: linq

In my application, i have used LINQ as following:

```
 var GroupedEmployyes = from e in EmpCollection
                                   group e by e.identifier into g
                                   select new { Employee= g, identifier = g.Key };
```

I am passing this group to some other function as following:

```
     Save(GroupedEmployyes)

     Save(IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Employee>> groupedEmployee)
     {



     }
```

How I will access the "Employee"  object and the "identifier " object from the "groupedEmployee" parameter using the Save method ?

Comment: Why have you got the `select` part? It's not doing you any good - it's just converting an `IGrouping<string, Employee>` into an `IEnumerable<T>` for an anonymous type which contains the same information. Your code won't currently compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your link expression creates objects of an anonymous type when you say `new { Employee= g, identifier = g.Key };`

To be able to get at those values in another function such as your `Save`, you need to create objects of a named type. If you can't be bothered to create a special class for this one use, use `System.Tuple`

On the other hand, it's odd that you're creating that pairing of employee with key, because `IGrouping` already does that for you, so for example:

```
 void Save(IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> groupedEmployee)
 {
     foreach (var group in groupedEmployee)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

         foreach (var emp in group)
             Console.WriteLine(emp.ToString());
     }
 }
```

You can call this with:

```
Save(EmpCollection.GroupBy(e => e.identifier));
```